# Why does does a jump to a case label cross initialization in this switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, initialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y, i;
    cin >> x >> y >> i;
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            // int r = x + y; -- OK
            int r = 1; // Failed to Compile
            cout << r;
            break;
        case 2:
            r = x - y;
            cout << r;
            break;
    };
}
```

G++ complains:

> ```
> <source>: In function 'int main()':
> <source>:14:14: error: jump to case label
>    14 |         case 2:
>       |              ^
> <source>:11:17: note:   crosses initialization of 'int r'
>    11 |             int r = 1; // Failed to Compile
>       |                 ^
> ```

My questions are:

1. What is `crosses initialization`?
2. Why do the first initializer `x + y` pass the compilation, but the latter failed?
3. What are the problems of so-called `crosses initialization`?

I know I should use brackets to specify the scope of `r`, but I want to know why, for example why non-POD could not be defined in a multi-case switch statement.

Comment: My understanding, given the answers below, for point 3 is that this error is an excessive restriction of c++. If r is not used after the label, there is no impact (even if the example here uses r, it can be removed in case 2 and the compiler would give the same error). The better proof is that it is allowed in C, and even in C11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Jump to case label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685471/error-jump-to-case-label)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The version with `int r = x + y;` won't compile either.

The problem is that it is possible for `r` to come to scope without its initializer being executed. The code would compile fine if you removed the initializer completely (i.e. the line would read `int r;`).

The best thing you can do is to limit the scope of the variable. That way you'll satisfy both the compiler and the reader.

```
switch(i)
{
case 1:
    {
        int r = 1;
        cout << r;
    }
    break;
case 2:
    {
        int r = x - y;
        cout << r;
    }
    break;
};
```

The Standard says (6.7/3):

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps from a point where a local variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has POD type (3.9) and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

Comment: But my G++ does allow `int r = x + y`.

Comment: Well, my g++ doesn't. Check again or upgrade the compiler.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful to me. I think that C compiler does not even allow declaration to come _after_ some code. Apparently C99 allows that though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859424/why-was-mixing-declarations-and-code-forbidden-up-until-c99

Answer (score 37):

You should put the contents of the `case` in brackets to give it scope, that way you can declare local variables inside it:

```
switch(i) {
    case 1:
        {
            // int r = x + y; -- OK
            int r = 1; // Failed to Compile
            cout << r;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps from a point where a local variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has POD type and is declared without an initializer.

```
[Example: Code:

void f()
{
  // ...
  goto lx;    // ill-formed: jump into scope of `a'
  // ...
 ly:
    X a = 1;
  // ...
 lx:
   goto ly;    // ok, jump implies destructor
 // call for `a' followed by construction
 // again immediately following label ly
}

--end example]
```

The transfer from the condition of a switch statement to a case label is considered a jump in this respect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide sources for your citations, this is C++03:6.7/3. It also happens to be the same paragraph I cited in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you promote your `r` variable before the `switch` statement.  If you want to use a variable across the `case` blocks, (or the same variable name but different usages), define it before the switch statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y, i;
    cin >> x >> y >> i;
// Define the variable before the switch.
    int r;
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            r = x + y
            cout << r;
            break;
        case 2:
            r = x - y;
            cout << r;
            break;
    };
}
```

One of the benefits is that the compiler does not have to perform local allocation *(a.k.a. pushing onto the stack)* in each `case` block.

A drawback to this approach is when cases "fall" into other cases (i.e. without using `break`), as the variable will have a previous value.

Comment: I would suggest doing it the other way around. Compiler does not have to perform "local allocation" in either case (and in practice it won't).