# C++ POCO run in thread issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco, runnable

I got one problem when compiling.

I recive error :

> In member function
>   'void CSConnection::onReadable(const
>   Poco::AutoPtr&)':|
>   CSConnection.cpp|92|error: no
>   matching function for call to
>   'Poco::ThreadPool::start(QuitHandler**)'|
>   CSConnection.cpp|92|note: candidates
>   are:|
>   c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2........\include\Poco\ThreadPool.h|122|note:
>   void Poco::ThreadPool::start(Poco::Runnable&)|
>   c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2........\include\Poco\ThreadPool.h|122|note:
>   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QuitHandler**' to
>   'Poco::Runnable&'|
>   c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2........\include\Poco\ThreadPool.h|127|note:
>   void Poco::ThreadPool::start(Poco::Runnable&, const string&)|
>   c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2........\include\Poco\ThreadPool.h|127|note:
>   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided| ||=== Build finished: 1
>   errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

Here is quithandler class :

```
class QuitHandler : public Runnable
{
    public:
        QuitHandler(){}
        CSConnection * _con;
        void run();
        virtual ~QuitHandler();
    protected:
    private:
        char * _packet;
};
```

Here error line

```
QuitHandler * qh;
qh = new QuitHandler();
WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(qh);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start method accepts reference, not a pointer: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ThreadPool.html#11337.

Quick fix would be:

```
QuitHandler qh;
WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(qh);
```

or

```
QuitHandler* qh = new QuitHandler();
WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(*qh);
```

Comment: Now i got this error : CSConnection.cpp|90|error:   crosses initialization of 'QuitHandler qh'|

Comment: Please post the minimal example demonstrating this error. Or read some explanations of what "crossing initialization" means, and you'll probably find it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392655/what-are-the-signs-of-crosses-initialization.

Comment: {} in switch fixed it, but application crashes when thread start, run function aren't called.

Comment: Well yes, because after "}" qh gets out of scope and is destroyed. You must redesign the code for "qh" not to be destroyed while the thread is running. I've edited the answer and put an alternative quick fix.

Comment: No, that's what I'm talking about. That's the problem - "qh" cannot be destroyed while it's needed. And it's needed to be executed in the thread you're creating. You must somehow arrange everything for "qh" to be deleted after the thread finishes.

Comment: it also crashes with :D
QuitHandler* qh = new QuitHandler();
                        qh->_con = this;
                        WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(*qh);

Comment: Then there's something more. Post the minimal example demonstrating the issue, in another question - this one concerns compilation error.