# C++ cross initiialization error

Tags: c++, authentication, codeblocks, registration, gnu

When compiling the following code it provides me with two errors; "jump to case label" and "crosses initialization of std::ofstream SaveLogin". I am currently using codeblocks with the gnu gcc compiler.

```
switch(choice) {
  case 1:
    // login
  case 2:
    // register
    ofstream SaveLogin;
    break;
  case 3:
    // reset password

;}
```

Thanks for viewing my question-EDIT: my question was flagged as a duplicate of another question but the question specified did not entirely conclude my problem. This post is specifically about my problem although I hope it can hope any other people who are having the same problem

Comment: In case it's not clear: those are two lines of the same error. The problem is that a jump to a `case` label crosses the initialisation of an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the signs of crosses initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392655/what-are-the-signs-of-crosses-initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is correct: C++ does not allow you to skip over a variable declaration in the same scope. `goto` is similarly restricted.

If you need `SaveLogin` for all cases then declare it above the `switch`. If you only need it for `case 2` then use scope blocks:

```
case 2 /*not directly relevant but there's no need for the parentheses*/:
{
    // register
    ofstream SaveLogin; /*ToDo - more logic here unless it's contained
                         fully within construction and destruction*/
    break;
}
case 3:
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small change to the code that should illustrate the problem:

```
switch(choice) {
  case 1:
    // login
  case 2:
    // register
    ofstream SaveLogin;
    break;
  case 3:
    // reset password
    SaveLogin << "whatever\n"; // added code
;}
```

That last line would be legal, because `SaveLogin` is in scope, but it would get executed only as part of `case 3`, which skips the initialization of `SaveLogin`. So the rule is that a jump (`switch` or `goto`) can't skip an initializer. One possibility, as @Bathsheba mentions, is to put the definition of `SaveLogin` above the case statement. Another possibility is to limit the scope of `SaveLogin` so that the jump doesn't bypass it:

```
case 2:
    {
    ofstream SaveLogin;
    break;
    }
case 3:
```

With the curly braces, `SaveLogin` is not in scope at `case 3` and the problem has gone away.